# Подставить данные в атрибут с помощью ReactJS, FormatJs и ReactIntl

Tags: reactjs

Делаю интернационализацию с помощью ReactJS и React Intlv.2

Обычно это выглядит так:

`<button type="button" className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.cancelDelete}>
   <FormattedMessage id="confirmNo" defaultMessage="NO" />
</button>`

Необходимо подставить данные в атрибут title тега span вместо "Add" для локализации.

```
<span className="glyphicon-green glyphicon glyphicon-ok" onClick={this.addTag} title="Add">
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно сделать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого существует [шnjection-api](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/API#injection-api) который позволяет использовать методы intl внутри React компонентов. Для начала, вам нужно обернуть ваш компонент используя `injectIntl()`, и потом вызвыть нужный метод используя `this.props.intl`

Доступны следующие методы:

- formatDate: (value: any, options?: object) => string,
- formatTime: (value: any, options?: object) => string,
- formatRelative: (value: any, options?: object) => string,
- formatNumber: (value: any, options?: object) => string,
- formatPlural: (value: any, options?: object) => string,
- formatMessage: (messageDescriptor: MessageDescriptor, values?: object) => string,
- formatHTMLMessage: (messageDescriptor: MessageDescriptor, values?: object) => string,

Пример:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {intlShape, injectIntl, defineMessages} from 'react-intl';

const messages = defineMessages({
    enUSDescription: {
        id: 'menu.item_en_us_description',
        defaultMessage: 'The default locale of this example app.',
    },
});

class LocalesMenu extends Component {
    render() {
        const {formatMessage} = this.props.intl;

        return (
            <menu>
                <li>
                    <a
                        href="/?locale=en-US"
                        title={formatMessage(messages.enUSDescription)}
                    >
                        en-US
                    </a>
                </li>
            </menu>
        );
    }
}

LocalesMenu.propTypes = {
    intl: intlShape.isRequired,
};

export default injectIntl(LocalesMenu);
```